# Reading user input until button pressed javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to web development, I have a requirement to read user input one after the other as the add button is clicked,until stop button is pressed and then display the user input in a list. How do I do it ?

```
<Title>To Do List</Title>
    <Body>
        <Button id = "AddBtn"  onClick = "Store()">Add</Button>
        <Button id = "StopBtn" onclick  = "Display()">Stop</Button>
        <input id = "ip" type = "text" >

        <script>
            function Store()
            {
                var tasks;
                tasks.push(document.getElementById('ip'));
            }
            function Display()
            {
                var i;
                for(i=0;i<tasks.length;i++)
                {
                    document.write(tasks[i]);
                }

            }

        </script>
    </Body>
```

Comment: This is a variable scoping issue. Move `var tasks = []` to be **above** `function Store()`. Also, using `document.write` will remove the rest of your document. Use DOM methods to show content instead

Comment: You probably want to get the input's value in the task array, so `document.getElementById('ip').value`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <Title>To Do List</Title>
</head>

<Body>
  <Button id="AddBtn" onclick="Store()">Add</Button>
  <Button id="StopBtn" onclick="Display()">Stop</Button>
  <input id="ip" type="text">
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>

  <script>
    var tasks = [];

    function Store() {

      tasks.push(document.getElementById('ip').value);
      document.getElementById("ip").value = "";
    }

    function Display() {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        var text = document.createTextNode(tasks[i]);
        item.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(item);

      }
      tasks = [];

    }
  </script>
</Body>

</html>
```

1. Javascript is case sensitive language.onClick supposed to be
   onclick.
2. you want to store more than one value.You need a array not a
   variable.
3. you want to save just the values in the array not the whole element.
4. you want to clear the input value after adding it to task array.
5. you need to get values from your array and create li elements with
   value.
6. you need a parent for your li items which can be ul,ol or div.
7. you have to add all created li elements to the parent.
8. after the loop finishes you can clear the array in display method.